# SSIS Data Flow task Integrity

Tags: sql, ssis

I was working in a scenario where I want if i load a file either it is loaded in database completely on not at all.

I wanna know if this is already handled in SSIS Data flow task(I guess not).

If not is there any way to handle this kind of situation.

Just an upper idea.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use transactions. Also if at all possible do all your cleaning/transforming in a staging table beforehand and make your final dataflow one from the staging table to the final prod location with no other steps. That wasy you can do waht you need to doand see the data as it was transformed so that you can research the problem if the final datalow rolls back in the transaction.